# Why do I get a large negative number as result?

Tags: c++

Why does my C++ code keep returning -1073741676 and not the values of the variables in code blocks?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int vans = 6;
    int trains = 5;
    int flights = 9;
    int scooters = 9;
    int cycles = 5;

    vans -= flights;
    trains /= cycles + cycles;
    flights /= scooters *= trains;
    -- scooters;
    cycles /= trains;

    cout << vans << trains << flights << scooters << cycles << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a division by zero here "cycles /= trains;".

Comment: To add to that: `cycles + cycles` is 10. `5/10` is zero, because you're doing integer division. Hence, the division by zero later.

Comment: Here is an online compiler showing that trains is 0 after `trains /= cycles + cycles;` : [https://ideone.com/OaDPgb](https://ideone.com/OaDPgb)

Comment: On a side note, your `cout` is not delimiting the values, so they are going to appear as one large number anyway. So, for example, if you removed your calculations, then you would output `65995`. You should add `<< ' '` or equivalent between each number so the output looks more like `6 5 9 9 5` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have a division by zero, which causes undefined behaviour, which means your program starts acting weirdly to put it simply.

You should read up more on integer and floating point math operations.

Basically what happens is this :

```
trains /= cycles + cycles;
```

conceptually becomes

```
   trains = trains / (cycles + cycles) 
   <=> trains = 5 / (5 + 5)
   <=> trains = 5 / 10
   <=> trains = 0
```

not 0.5, because these are integers, so only whole values are kept

If you replace all the `int`s by `float`s, the program should work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

A good trick that I always use is simply to check any debugger (online or offline), I use VS 2019 most of my time.

Using a debugger, there is something called "Watch" which simply means you're going to watch live the values of the variables in each step of this code.

Here, we see at the line:

```
trains /= cycles + cycles;
```

This means:

```
trains = trains / (cycles + cycles)
```

Which evaluates to 0.

as trains / cycles + cycles reach 0.5, which is 0 (Because trains data type is int)
Now, this is a very famous problem is that you forgot that this is an integral division and according to this [article](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=352857&seqNum=4#:%7E:text=If%20both%20operands%20are%20integers%2C%20C%2B%2B%20performs%20integer%20division.,making%20the%20result%20floating%2Dpoint.):

> If both operands are integers, C++ performs integer division. That means any >fractional part of the answer is discarded, making the result an integer. If one or >both operands are floating-point values, the fractional part is kept, making the >result floating-point.

So, in other words, to fix this problem you edit your code to this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int vans = 6;
    float trains = 5;
    float flights = 9;
    int scooters = 9;
    float cycles = 5;

    vans -= flights;
    trains /= cycles + cycles;
    flights /= scooters *= trains;
    -- scooters;
    cycles /= trains;

    cout << vans << trains << flights << scooters << cycles << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I,e: If you want to keep fractions, always make sure that the data type of the variable should be either: double or float.

Best regards,